# Entity Framework creates new data in database instead of using exsisting one (even when I don't tell to do that)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently facing a very strange problem. I'm making some kind of dictionary, so I use 3 classes: `Word` (for every single word), `Translation` (that stores two words that means the same but in different languages) and `Language` (that stores information about language).

My server code is actually a WebAPI project. Here is my C# API controller and 2 functions that are used by it:

```
//Controller:

// POST: api/Translations
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTranslation(TranslationsViewModel tvm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (tvm.language1ID == tvm.language2ID)
    {
        return BadRequest("Languages have to be different");
    }

    Translation translation = tvm.toTranslation();

    db.Translations.Add(translation);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok("Translation created succesfully");
}

public Translation toTranslation(TranslationsViewModel tvm)
{
    Translation translation = new Translation {
        WordsLanguage1 = new List<Word>(),
        WordsLanguage2 = new List<Word>(),
        Tags = new List<Tag>()
    };

    addWords(tvm.wordsL1, tvm.language1ID).ForEach(w => translation.WordsLanguage1.Add(w));
    addWords(tvm.wordsL2, tvm.language2ID).ForEach(w => translation.WordsLanguage2.Add(w));
    translation.ReviewInterval = tvm.reviewInterval;
    translation.Notes = tvm.notes;
    addTags(tvm.tags).ForEach(o => translation.Tags.Add(o));

    return translation;
}

public List<Word> addWords(string givenWords, int languageID)
{
    List<Word> wordsToReturn = new List<Word>();

    char[] delimiters = new[] { ' ', ',', ';' };  // List of your delimiters
    string[] splittedArray = givenWords.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var word in splittedArray)
    {
        wordsToReturn.Add(new Word
        {
            Content = word,
            Language = db.Languages.Find(languageID)
        });
    }

    return wordsToReturn;
}
```

Here are models of my C# app:

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public ImagesSet Images { get; set; } //przy "get" wypadałoby wygenerować nowe obrazki, jeśli nie ma
    public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            if (Translations != null)
            {
                ICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();

                foreach (var translation in Translations)
                {
                    foreach (var tag in translation.Tags)
                    {
                        tags.Add(tag);
                    }
                }
                return tags;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Translation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Word> WordsLanguage1 { get; set; } //słowo + synonimy
    public virtual ICollection<Word> WordsLanguage2 { get; set; } //słowo + synonimy
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? LastReviewed { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? NextReview
    {
        get
        {
            if (LastReviewed != null)
            {
                DateTime someDate = (DateTime)LastReviewed;
                return someDate.AddDays(ReviewInterval);
            }
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public int ReviewInterval { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int ActiveImage { get; set; }

    public TranslationsViewModel toTVM()
    {
        TranslationTranslator tt = new TranslationTranslator();
        return tt.toTVM(this);
    }
}

public class TranslationsViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /* Id language1 */
    public int language1ID { get; set; }

    /* Id language2 */
    public int language2ID { get; set; }

    /* Word 1 and synonyms */
    public string wordsL1 { get; set; }

    /* Word 2 and synonyms */
    public string wordsL2 { get; set; }

    /* Tags separated by comma or space */
    public string tags { get; set; }

    /* Notes */
    public string notes { get; set; }

    public int reviewInterval { get; set; }

    //Changing it to "Translation" class
    public Translation toTranslation()
    {
        TranslationTranslator tt = new TranslationTranslator();
        return tt.toTranslation(this);
    }
}

public class Language
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

What is `toTranslation()` and `TranslationViewModel`: because of structure of the `Translation` model, I can't send it through WebAPI to client because there is something like: "Self referencing loop".

So I created other model: `TranslationViewModel` that can be easily send to client. `toTranslation()` simply changes `TranslationViewModel` to a `Translation`.

What is `addWords()`: it changes one string of words separated by commas, to list of strings with those words. It is separate function, because I'm gonna check there if there is currently a similar word in db (to avert some duplicates).

And finally what is the problem?

Strange thing happens here. As you see in `addWords()`, I assign `Language` to every `Word`. I provide some `languageID`, then find it in db and add it to `Word`. So if I have `languageID = 1`, I should have got a `Word` with `Language` with `ID = 1`.

The problem is: Entity Framework clones `Language` with `ID = 1` (creates new one, the same as no. 1) and assign this new `Language` to my `Word`. So instead of `Word` with `Language ID = 1` I get a `Word` with `Langauge ID = 2`.

So when I create 10 new words, my API creates 10 new languages named "English". But I want to have 1 "English" language with 10 Words assigned to it.

PS: (offtopic) Is using TranslationViewModel the best way to send information to client/javascript? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Instead of `Language = db.Languages.Find(languageID)` for creating new `Word` rather set `Word.LanguageId` to the correct one

Comment: @3dd Do I need to create this "languageId" variable in my <odel or it is created antomatically?

Comment: No add it on the `Word` entity and use `[ForeignKey("Language")]` to setup ef so it knows it links to `Language`

Comment: Are you saving your list of words with use of another `DbContext` object?

While you are reading `Language` from `DbContext`, its state can't become `Added`, so there is no reason for `Entity Framework` to add new row into db.

Comment: @3dd and what if I have the collection of some objects? Like: "public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }". Can I do it the same way (assigning ID instead of adding entire object)? How?

Comment: @Ludwik11 in that case you'll need to use the `ModelBuilder` to create it, something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>().HasMany(f => f.TradeUnions).WithMany(t => t.Firms).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("FirmId"); m.MapRightKey("TradeUnionId");});`